# INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Updating the whoId fields for shared activities is not allowed

Tags: apex, event

So I am getting the error in the subject. I have an event and then through a javascript interface I edit the event and I change who the primary contact (the whoId) is. But when I try to save I get the error:

INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Updating the whoId fields for shared activities is not allowed

It seems to be saying that I cant change the who Id of an event just because the shared activities is on but that cant be true. So can anyone tell me what causes this problem?

EDIT: I see where its going wrong. But then can someone tell me how I change the WhoId when the shared activities is on?

Comment: Please see below link to share activity using eventRelation object: developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventattendee.htm also if you want to change primary then you may have to recreate event after deleting former.

Comment: Deleting the event isnt an option. Theres other references to the event in other objects. But I am deleting the EventRelation objects and recreating all of them